# Google Analytics: Invalid value for filters parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What are valid parameters for google analytics filters? I have looked on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters and trying to get info for custom ga:campaign and ga:adContent

```
query: {
'ids': IDS,
'dimensions': 'ga:date',
'metrics': 'ga:pageviews, ga:sessions',
'filters' : 'ga:source%3D%3Dfacebook;ga:campaign%3D%3Dmycampaing;ga:adContent%3D%3Dtest'
},
```

Query fails with the error:

```
"Invalid value 'ga:source%3D%3Dfacebook;ga:campaign%3D%3Dmycampaing;ga:adContent%3D%3Dtest' for filters parameter."
```

How can I get report from google analytics for my  ga:campaign and etc?

Comment: What client library are you using? Note the documentation you linked to states "URL Encoding: The Google API client libraries automatically encode the filter operators."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I feed the same combination of filters, dimensions and metrics to the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) I get no error message but a result (with all metrics being 0 because obviously my campaigns are named differently, but otherwise fine).

Only difference is that I did *not* encode the filters - I think if you use the API client it takes care of url encoding, so try and use "==" instead of "%3D%3D" and this should work fine.